# Overlaying a Image over a whole web page

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to overlay a repeating image over a entire web page? If so, How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("image.png") repeat;
}
```

You probably want to put the div at the very end of the html to ensure it's above everything else on the page, alternatively you could use z-indexing.

Comment: That works except there is one problem it won't let me click anything behind the overlay.

Comment: @Joshua: I take it this is a partially transparent overlay? I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Maybe if you explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish (visually and functionally) it will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: Basically I have a partially transparent image which I would like to overaly of the web page tog ive a kind of tint.

Answer (score 1):

You can't click any of the elements on your page cause you are covering the entire page with a `<div>`, so all your elements get hidden behind that `<div>`.
However, you can 'apply the tint' to your body background in this manner -

```
.body{background-image: url("overlay image"), url("your bg image");}
```

Make sure your overlay image has appropriate transparency to it.