# Displaying page loading gif in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a ajax submit using dojo.xhrpost. 
It takes quite a while to get the response. 
So i want to display a page loading gif till i get the response.
At the same time I kinda want to hide or reduce the visibility of the page so that the user cant click anything on the page till the response has been received. 
I want to overlay the page loading gif over the entire web page till the response is received.

Comment: That's great. Good luck with that! :)

Comment: I was able to figure out the gif loading part. But i cant seem to overlay it over the entire html file.

Comment: I think i got it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212578/overlaying-a-image-over-a-whole-web-page

Comment: Should have done some more research. Found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show the loading gif, wrap it in a div that covers the page with some low opacity.

In your dom, you can stick something like

```
<div id="overlay"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

with style like

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.3;
display:none;
z-index: 100; /* should be large enough to be on top of everything */
```

Then before the ajax call, you show that div

```
dojo.query("#overlay").style("display", "block");
```

And then when the load is successful, you hide it

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost({ ..., 
                              load: function() {
                                 dojo.query("#overlay").style("display","none");
                               }
                             });
```

I haven't done much work with Dojo but it seems like this ought to work.  If not, I bet it's really close.

As long as you have no event bindings on the #overlay div, users should not be able to interact with the page until the div is hidden.

You may also want to hide the overlay on error too (checkout the error callback) so that if your request fails, at least the user can still get to the stuff on the page.

Comment: I found a dojo widget for this.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/widget/Standby.html#id4

Comment: Nice.  If you look into the widget code, it probably looks similar to the above, but if Dojo built a widget, that seems like the best solution.  Let them maintain that widget code as well.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

use a div with below css. All you need to do is show/hid this div

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: black url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xn2gmPb9TfM/SBZwjqwS6MI/AAAAAAAABZw/uMVQlcxlosA/s400/loading-icon.gif) no-repeat center center;
}​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4k9cH/

Answer (score 1):

Add a DIV with a specific name (lets say 'loading') that is 100% in width and height and has a (semi) transparent background (image). Add an inner DIV (lets say 'loadingInner') that holds the loading gif. Set the loading DIVs to display: none by default.

Then, when you access external information, show the loading DIVs with jQuery:

```
function showLoading() {
    var loadControl = $("#loading");
    if (loadControl) {
        $("#loadingInner").show();
        $("#loading").show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may also help for the loading image to appear on whole window during ajax call pending status:
http://www.edwardawebb.com/web-development/cakephp/disable-page-show-translucent-progress-bar